# Circular buffer with two indexes

Tags: c#, multithreading, circular-buffer

I would like to made a circular buffer which would have two indexes:

- WriteIndex (controlled by first thread) to write new value in buffer
- ReadIndex (controlled by second thread) to read value from buffer and analyse it

So, how can I pause the Thread when two indexes are in the same position.
I mean, if u didn't write any new data, you can't read it, so if writeindex and readindex are at the same position, you have to only write new data, not read it.

How to block thread untill something happen?

Comment: Do you actually need a circular buffer or would any bounded thread-safe collection do?

Comment: I don't really need it, but i need to save some data for a while. I am reading bytes from device by  FTD2XX_NET and then I'm trying to find network packet, check CRC etc. So the first thread should read data by FTDI and save them to buffer and the second one should read buffer and looking for network packets

I hope you understand me. It's hard for me to describe ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're looking for is already in the BCL: [`BlockingCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287223(v=vs.110).aspx).

It is thread-safe: it has an [`Add()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287137.aspx) to add items and a blocking [`Take()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx) that blocks ("pauses the calling thread") until an item is available.

As mentioned in a now-removed comment: this is indeed not truly a circular buffer that disposes or overwrites items once the maximum has been reached. You can set an upper bound to the collection size though; this will make `Add()` block until there is more space.

Comment: The comment was removed because the OP doesn't really want a circular buffer. A BlockingCollection<T> with an upper bound is enough.